# finite state machine in telegram bot - go

Tags: go, telegram-bot

i am developing a tg bot for notes and reminders and trying to implement FMS.
thing i need to do:

- default state: commands /start, /help; also bot uses this state after successful saving note/reminder to db
- note state: for editing notes (creating, deleting, search by text/date)
- reminders state (the most complex for me): must contain following states: name of reminder, date, time. also is used for deleting reminders

i wanna create a single interface with method e.g. handle(). i wanna avoid using switch case construction for checking state and i want my bot to handle commands differently depending on the state.

how to implement it? here is my code:

controller - used for commands:

```
type Controller struct {
    srv     *server.Server
    handler commandHandler
}

type commandHandler interface {
    Handle(ctx tele.Context) error
}

func New(handler commandHandler, srv *server.Server) *Controller {
    return &Controller{srv, handler}
}
func (c *Controller) SetupBot() error {
    // commands

    c.srv.Bot.Handle(startCmd, func(ctx tele.Context) error {
        // handling /start
    })
   ...
   // other commands
```

server - mostly contains interfaces to interact with DB:

```
type Server struct {
    NoteEditor          noteEditor
    ReminderEditor      reminderEditor
    UserEditor          userEditor
    TimezoneCacheEditor timezoneCacheEditor
    UserCacheEditor     userCacheEditor
    Calendar            *calendar.Calendar
    Logger              *logger.Logger
    Bot                 *tele.Bot
    State               state
}
```

state:

```
type State struct {
    CurrentState map[int64]StateEditor
}

type StateEditor interface {
    Next(tgID int64)
    Get() string
}

func New() *State {
    curState := make(map[int64]StateEditor)
    return &State{curState}
}

const (
    Note       = "note"
    Reminder   = "reminder"
    Default    = "default"
    SearchNote = "searchNote"
)

func (s *State) Set(name string, tgID int64) {
    switch name {
    case Note:
        s.CurrentState[tgID] = newNote()
        fmt.Println("set state to note for user ", tgID)
    case SearchNote:
        s.CurrentState[tgID] = newSearch()
        fmt.Println("set state to search note for user ", tgID)
    case Reminder:
        s.CurrentState[tgID] = newReminder()
        fmt.Println("set state to reminder for user ", tgID)
    case Default:
        s.CurrentState[tgID] = newDefault()
        fmt.Println("set state to default for user ", tgID)
    default:
        s.CurrentState[tgID] = newDefault()
        fmt.Println("set state to default for user ", tgID)
    }
    fmt.Println(s.CurrentState)
}

func (s *State) Get(tgID int64) string {
    return s.CurrentState[tgID].Get()
}
```

the problem came up when i tried to implement how to handle text from user:

```
func (s *Server) Handle(ctx tele.Context) error {
    switch s.State.Get(ctx.Chat().ID) {
    case state_pkg.Note:
        return s.CreateNote(ctx)
    case state_pkg.Reminder:
        return s.reminder(ctx)
    }

    return nil
}
```

what i would like to see:

```
func (s *Server) Handle(ctx tele.Context) error {
    return s.handler.handle()
}
```

thank you in advance!